# Conversion of huge XML to CSV

Tags: xml, csv

I am trying to uplaod the uniprot database into neo4j to create graph database.
Uniprot database is available in xml format. I want to convert the XML format into CSV format.
Though there are many online tools for conversion, they are limited for only small file sizes.
Can any one help me in this regard?
Uniprot database size is 5.2 GB

Thanks in Advance
Pavan Kumar Alluri

Answer (score 1):

In Java I think using SAXParser you can resolve this problem as SAXParser doesn't need all xml data to be in memory at one time.

Comment: Similarly, you don't need to keep the CSV in memory either, you can write it out to a file as it happens.